# Convert for loop to stream

Tags: java

How to convert this block of code for loop into stream.

**I am dividing my data list into partition on basis of partitionSize.. Also in last bit of code using sys out but will be calling a function inside..**

I wanted to convert all for loop used in this part of code to streams

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Long> a = Arrays.asList(11L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 23L, 14L, 38L, 49L, 50L, 68L, 79L, 87L);
    int partitionSize = 4;
    List<List<Long>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i += partitionSize)
        partitions.add(a.subList(i, Math.min(i + partitionSize, a.size())));

    for (List<Long> list : partitions)
        System.out.println(list);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 12, 13, 9]
[10, 11, 23, 14]
[38, 49, 50, 68]
[79, 87]
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What is partitionSize here? What is sample input and output?

Comment: For the first loop there is no point in using streams, as you need the index value inside the loop. 
For the second one you would do this `partitions.stream().forEach(System.out::println)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int partitionSize = 4;
    List<Long> a = Arrays.asList(11L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 23L, 14L, 38L, 49L, 50L, 68L, 79L, 87L);

    List<List<Long>> partitions = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < a.size(), i -> i + partitionSize)
                                           .mapToObj(i -> a.subList(i, Math.min(a.size(), i + partitionSize)))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

    partitions.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 12, 13, 9]
[10, 11, 23, 14]
[38, 49, 50, 68]
[79, 87]
```

Comment: Getting following error
 error: method iterate in interface IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
    List<List<Long>> partitions = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < a.size(), i -> i + partitionSize)
                                           ^
  required: int,IntUnaryOperator
  found: int,(i)->i < a.size(),(i)->i + p[...]nSize
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: getting error cannot convert boolean to int on line i< a.size()

Comment: I check this in 30 minutes

Comment: It worked like this.. but please let me know is it the correct way

 List<List<Long>> partitions = IntStream.iterate(0,  
  i -> i + partitionSize).takeWhile(i -> i < a.size())
               .mapToObj(i -> a.subList(i, Math.min(a.size(), i + partitionSize)))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Your approach is also ok. I have checked mine, it works fins.

Comment: Your approach also worked.. It was not working as I was using Java 8 , but on Java 11 it works fine and I am also using Java 11 in my code.. Thanks a  ton :)

Comment: I also need to have it with Java 8, is there any way?